# Authenticate against MongoDB using DelphiMongoDB from Grijjy

Tags: mongodb, delphi

I am using DelphiMongoDB from Grijjy ([DelphiMongoDB](https://github.com/grijjy/DelphiMongoDB)) which is working pretty cool so far. But I can't find any functions to authenticate against a MongoDB. Did anybody getting this work or figured out how to do it?
Thanks and best regards

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help. I already used TMongoWire, but DelphiMongoDB has more options and is more powerful (except authentication). FireDAC Mongo requires Enterprise version of Delphi. The other link doesn't help, because I don't have problems with authentication mechanisms in MongoDB , but using the specific library mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**  The most up to date version of the Grijjy driver now supports TLS, X.509 client certificate authentication, SCRAM SHA-1 and SHA-256 authentication.  We have also tested it against MongoDB Atlas instance at Azure.

Here is a simple example of how to use the authentication.

```
var
  Settings: TgoMongoClientSettings;
  Client: IgoMongoClient;
  Database: IgoMongoDatabase;
  Collection: IgoMongoCollection;
  Doc: TgoBsonDocument;

begin
  Settings := TgoMongoClientSettings.Create;
  Settings.Secure := True;
  Settings.AuthMechanism := TgoMongoAuthMechanism.SCRAM_SHA_1;
  Settings.AuthDatabase := 'admin';
  Settings.Username := 'username';
  Settings.Password := 'password';
  //Settings.QueryFlags := [TgoMongoQueryFlag.SlaveOk];
  Client := TgoMongoClient.Create('my.mongodb.server.com', 27017, Settings);
  Database := Client.GetDatabase('mydatabase');
  Collection := Database.GetCollection('mycollection');

  for Doc in Collection.Find() do
    Writeln(Doc.ToJson(TgoJsonWriterSettings.Pretty));
end;
```

**Legacy:** Yes, the published Grijjy driver does not support authentication, but we have tested it internally and may add this ability in the near future to Github.  You are also welcome to make a pull request if you want to adapt the following changes:

MongoDB currently supports 2 types of authentication, SCRAM and x.509 Certificate Authentication.  Internally we have tested the x.509 Certificate Authentication, but the current driver on Github does not reflect this ability.  We have not experimented with SCRAM yet.

To make it work with the MongoDB driver we published on Github, you may have to make a couple of changes.

1. You need to create a self-signed CA and certificate for your MongoDB server.
2. You need to configure your MongoDB server to use certs.
3. You need to create a self-signed certificate for your MongoDB client or clients.  You can use the same cert for all clients.
4. You need to enable SSL/TLS connections and use your client certificate with the MongoDB driver.

## 1 To create all the certificates, you need an existing CA or create a self-signed CA.  You can use the openssl.exe binary to do most of this:

Create root certificate authority (ca.pem and privkey.pem):

```
openssl req -out ca.pem -new -x509 -days 3650 -subj "/C=US/ST=California/O=Company/CN=root/emailAddress=root@domain.com"
```

To create a self-signed certificate for your MongoDB server (server.pem):

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -key server.key -new -out server.req -subj "/C=US/ST=California/O=Company/CN=db.myserver.com/emailAddress=user@domain.com"
openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 3650
type server.key server.crt > server.pem
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server.pem
```

## 2 To configure MongoDB to use certs on the Windows version (similar on other versions), edit the c:\data\mongod.cfg:

```
  systemLog:
      destination: file
      path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
  storage:
      dbPath: c:\data\db
  net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1
      ssl:
        mode: requireSSL
        PEMKeyFile: c:\data\server.pem
        CAFile: c:\data\ca.pem
        {allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true }
        {allowInvalidHostnames: true }
```

You may need allowInvalidHostnames to True if you are using a self signed certificate.

## 3 To create a self-signed certificate for your MongoDB client (client1.pem):

```
openssl genrsa -out client1.key 2048
openssl req -key client1.key -new -out client1.req -subj "/C=US/ST=California/O=Company/CN=client1/emailAddress=user@domain.com"
openssl x509 -req -in client1.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial ca.srl -out client1.crt -days 3650
type client1.key client1.crt > client1.pem
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem client1.pem
```

Note: You will also need to use the client certificate in whatever tool you are using to admin the MongoDB server.

## 4 To enable SSL/TLS connections for MongoDB driver you may have to change the source files.  Our unit Grijjy.Http shows how to enable the driver for ‘https’.  Essentially you need to do 2 things to the Connection inside the Grijjy.MongoDB.Protocol unit *probably* within the method TgoMongoProtocol.Connect :

1. Set Connection.SSL := True;
2. Set the Connection.Certificate to the client1.pem you created.

You will have to do some testing, but I hope it points you in the correct direction to make it work.  Would love your contribution to the open source project if you can.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can understand the sources, https://github.com/grijjy/DelphiMongoDB/ doesn't support authentication.

Also from the source, https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire doesn't either.

FireDAC Mongo uses the C Mongo client library, which supports authentication.

Our Open Source [SynMongoDB.pas](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynMongoDB.pas) supports authentication, FPC and almost all Delphi versions (even pre-Unicode). Using variant late-binding to access the BSON/JSON content, it is pretty easy to work with it. Just check [the corresponding documentation pages](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITLE_218). You can write for instance:

```
var doc: variant;
...
  doc := Coll.FindOne(5);
  writeln('Name: ',doc.Name);
  writeln('Number: ',doc.Number);
```

or

```
var docs: TVariantDynArray;
...
  Coll.FindDocs(docs);
  for i := 0 to high(docs) do
    writeln('Name: ',docs[i].Name,'  Number: ',docs[i].Number);
```

The `TMongoClient.OpenAuth` method supports both old/deprecated MONGODB-CR method, and the new SCRAM-SHA-1 method:

```
Client := TMongoClient.Create('localhost',27017);
  try
    DB := Client.OpenAuth('mydb','mongouser','mongopwd');
    ...
```

Note that even if it is part of the *mORMot* framework, this unit is stand-alone: you don't need to use the ORM, SOA, or MVC parts of the framework - even if it works very well with the ORM, and is [able to convert SQL-like statements into MongoDB pipelines](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITLE_228), which is a unique very powerful feature. Another unique feature is proper `Decimal128` support.

Over a network, also ensure that you use a TLS connection to the server. `SynMongoDB.pas`  can do that under Windows, with no external OpenSSL library needed (it uses the raw Windows SO API).